# Sqlite3 is readonly on webserver?

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, database-connection

I install sqlite db manager on visual studio and create my database.
I added this db file to "app_data > myDB" (no ext.)

It works perfect on visual studio using debug mode.But when i publish this project to web , my data is getting from db perfectly also my update button is working and saying its done !

Unfourtunately when i refresh page come back my old data , its not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it ,You have to set permission on db folder also , sqlite version must be defined in  your connection string : Like this :

```
data source=|path|\MYSQLITE_DB; Version=3;
```